# Quantidade dos produtos serem diferenciados no carrinho de compras

Tags: php, jquery

Colegas.

Perdoem-me se não soube expressar o que realmente quero no título, pois não consegui achar uma definição correta a não ser explicando por aqui.

Tenho um carrinho de compras onde os produtos são listados conforme a compra do cliente e que estão armazenados em uma tabela do BD, porém estou usando um recurso via Jquery que mostra a quantidade dos produtos e altera clicando no botão + ou -. Vejam a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código é esse para cada produto:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="quantity">
       <div class="quantity-select">
           <div class="entry value-minus">&nbsp;</div>
           <div class="entry value"><span>1</span></div>
           <div class="entry value-plus active">&nbsp;</div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.value-plus').on('click', function(){
var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
if(newVal < 8) divUpd.text(newVal);
  var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-nome]').data('nome'); // Funcional
  trocar = valor.replace(",",".");  
  valorTTotal =  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
  valorTotal = trocar + 1;
  vv = parseFloat(valorTotal) + parseFloat(valorTTotal);  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = vv.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = vv.toFixed(2);
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
       data:{ valor: vv.toFixed(2) },
      url: "atualizar-carrinho.php",
      success: function(resposta){
     }
   });


  var divUpd = $(this).parent().find('.value'), newVal1 = parseInt(divUpd.text(), 10)+1;
if(newVal1 < <?php echo $numero; ?>) divUpd.text(newVal);
  var valor = $(this).closest('tr').find('td[data-nome]').data('nome'); // Funcional
  trocar = valor.replace(",",".");  
  valorTTotal =  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
  valorTotal = trocar + 1;
  vv = parseFloat(valorTotal) + parseFloat(valorTTotal);  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = vv.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("subtotal").innerHTML = vv.toFixed(2);
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
       data:{ valor: vv.toFixed(2) },
      url: "atualizar-carrinho.php",
      success: function(resposta){
     }
   });       
});
```

A linha:

```
if(newVal < 8) divUpd.text(newVal);
```

Mostra a quantidade que os campos terão, porém aqui que entra o meu desafio. Cada produto vindo do BD tem sua própria quantidade. Como eu faria para integrar nesse código? A integração seria os resultados vindo do banco fica PHP.

```
<?php
 while($jmProdutos = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlProdutos)){
    .....
   $qtdProduto = $jmProdutos->Quantidade;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você está guardando no banco de dados o estado do carrinho de cada cliente, correto?

Você precisa incluir no `HTML` a chave primária da compra e passar isso no `Ajax` que você está mandando pro servidor, aí é só atualizar. Só aconselho usar o método `POST` no `Ajax` por questão de boas práticas (`GET` não se deve usar para modificar o banco de dados).

Exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<div class="produto" data-id="123">
   [Nome do produto, preço, imagem etc]
   <input name="qtd" value="1" /> 
   <button id="qtdup">+</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#qtdup').on('click', function(ev){
   [aumenta o número no input qtd e pega o número, como já foi feito na pergunta]
   var id_do_produto = $('#contaup').parent().data('id'); // aqui basta navegar pelo DOM e encontrar a div, tr ou o que você estiver usando para guardar o id do produto no carrinho
   $.post({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'json',
       data:{ id: id_do_produto, qtd: valor_de_qtd },
      url: "atualizar-carrinho.php",
      success: function(resposta){
     }
   });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
 $produto_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
 $produto_qtd = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['qtd']);
 $sqlProdutos = $mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM carrinho_produtos WHERE id_carrinho = $produto_id");
 while($produtos = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlProdutos)){
    .....
   $qtdProduto = $produtos->Quantidade;
   $qtdProduto = $produto_qtd;
}
 mysql_query($conn, "UPDATE carrinho_produtos SET Quantidade = $produto_qtd WHERE id_carrinho = $produto_id");
```

Comment: Olá Daniel. Obrigado pelo retorno, mas infelizmente não consegui compreendê-lo. Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Claro, só me fala uma coisa: quais as colunas que tem no banco de dados dos pedidos? Tem um ``ID`` ou coisa parecida?

Comment: Bom, fiz o exemplo pensando em coisas que todo mundo tem no banco de dados e usando o mysqli como você já parece estar acostumado.

Comment: Obrigado Daniel